# How to obtain DbProviderServices for System.Data.EntityClient?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I'm migrating an EF6 DB-First console app into a Code Library.
I'm using MySQL, BTW.
As a part of this, I'm moving the app.config-based stuff to C#-based due to the issues of having app.config based stuff in a DLL.

I'm generating the connection string via `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` and `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`, and in order to use EF6 I need to set
 
`EntityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.EntityClient"`

I have it mostly working, except for I get an exception:

```
The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.EntityClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
```

which I take to indicate that I need to set the DbProviderServices for EntityClient.

I am successfully setting my DbProviderServices for `System.Data.SqlClient` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` thus:

```
this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
this.SetProviderServices("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices());
```

(System.Data.SqlClient doesn't appear to be necessary, but it compiles & runs :)

**So now, the question** 
I still need to do this:

```
this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.EntityClient", something);
```

but despite lots of searhing & experimenting, I can't figure it out.
Does anyone know the proper syntax to create/retrieve a `DbProviderServices` instance for `System.Data.EntityClient` ?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't you set the provider to `"MySql.Data.MySqlClient"`?

Comment: I'm doing that in my EntityConnectionStringBuilder ctor

Comment: `EntityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.EntityClient"` <-- are you sure you need that in the first place?